# Pulling data from Django database and populating lists for user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, web

**I'd like to preface this with first - thank you for anyone willing to listen to my question - it may be a bit complex and second I'm very new to web development so I'm sorry if I sound dumb.**

I'm making a website that essentially allows admins *(Professors)* to input courses based on specific majors, and allows users *(Students)* to select what courses they've taken so far - and based on that input - display what courses they must **still** take to complete their degree.

In the Django admin page - it allows admins to create courses offered and one of the parameters is the major affiliated with the specific course. I then want the users (Students) to be able to select one of the majors (there are nine)  - and dependent on what major they select - choose from the available courses provided affiliated with that major. After the user selects what courses they've taken it would redirect them to a page that displays all the remaining courses they must take.

My question is, how do I take the data inputted by the admins, and based on the major they provide - send that data to a major specific database in django?

*For example* - if the admin creates a course and selects CS as the major, how do I then send that course information (Course Name, PreReqs, etc.) to another data base that specifically holds all CS courses provided?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "send the data"? I assume you have a table of major specific course lists and a table of courses that a student has taken. You just have to read/compare the two tables and display the courses not yet taken.

Comment: @DKDK Essentially I meant take the data inputted by the Admin, and whatever data they input for a course - take that information and migrate it into another subsection database that deals with specifically CS courses.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. How about not making a separate table for cs course and just filtering the values of the overall course table based on major?

Comment: Could you do something like this using django? Im not using php or MySQL, just the django admin portal.